# C++ calls Python - error LNK2019

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

I used c++ to call Python in my project and it always goes well on my Visual Studio. But my teacher got the follow errors when he opened my project on his Visual Studio:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Py_Finalize referenced in function "int __cdecl main_CcallPy(int)" (?main_CcallPy@@YAHH@Z)
>   1>demo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PyString_AsString referenced in function "int __cdecl main_CcallPy(int)" (?main_CcallPy@@YAHH@Z)
>   1>demo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PyObject_CallObject referenced in function "int __cdecl main_CcallPy(int)" (?main_CcallPy@@YAHH@Z)
>   1>demo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PyTuple_SetItem referenced in function "int __cdecl main_CcallPy(int)" (?main_CcallPy@@YAHH@Z)
>   1>demo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Py_BuildValue referenced in function "int __cdecl main_CcallPy(int)" (?main_CcallPy@@YAHH@Z)
>   1>demo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PyTuple_New referenced in function "int __cdecl main_CcallPy(int)" (?main_CcallPy@@YAHH@Z)
>   1>demo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PyCallable_Check referenced in function "int __cdecl main_CcallPy(int)" (?main_CcallPy@@YAHH@Z)
>   1>demo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PyDict_GetItemString referenced in function "int __cdecl main_CcallPy(int)" (?main_CcallPy@@YAHH@Z)
>   1>demo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PyModule_GetDict referenced in function "int __cdecl main_CcallPy(int)" (?main_CcallPy@@YAHH@Z)
>   1>demo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PyImport_Import referenced in function "int __cdecl main_CcallPy(int)" (?main_CcallPy@@YAHH@Z)
>   1>demo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PyString_FromString referenced in function "int __cdecl main_CcallPy(int)" (?main_CcallPy@@YAHH@Z)
>   1>demo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PyRun_SimpleStringFlags referenced in function "int __cdecl main_CcallPy(int)" (?main_CcallPy@@YAHH@Z)
>   1>demo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Py_IsInitialized referenced in function "int __cdecl main_CcallPy(int)" (?main_CcallPy@@YAHH@Z)
>   1>demo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Py_Initialize referenced in function "int __cdecl main_CcallPy(int)" (?main_CcallPy@@YAHH@Z)

The version of our Visual Studio are the same, and I checked the configuration of the project properties and they are also the same. 
How can I fix it? Thanks :)

Comment: Check  Additional Library Directories in your Project there should be some path that is available on your System but not your Teachers' system.

Comment: Try using /VERBOSE. in Linker it will show the libs with which its linking. then you can compare the libraries from your system and other system.

Comment: Great! I found the problem by using /VERBOSE.Thank you! :)